# How I can see a host name of my Pixel phone?

Tags: android, mdns

I want to access to the phone with mDNS to transfer data from my Linux computer.
How I can see the phone's hostname?

I have tried `adb shell getprop net.hostname` but nothing to show.

My phone is:

- Android 14
- Pixel 6 (it means that "stock Android" is installed on the Phone)

Comment: Who told you it has a host name?

Comment: Usually Android uses the name that has been entered in Settings -> About this phone -> Device name. Note that spaces in the name re converted to dashes `-`.